# Highcharts - Fix the Width of the xAxis Categories (and Wrap them)

Tags: highcharts

I have a [bar chart](http://jsfiddle.net/vCrc7/1/) with some longer xAxis categories (URLs). I would like to set the width of the display area for these categories and have them wrap accordingly. As it currently stands, the categories are forcing my chart area too far to the right.

### Here is my code:

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart:{
        type:'bar',
        height:1500
    },
    title:{text:false},
    legend:{enabled:false},
    xAxis:{
        title:{text:null},
        categories:[
            'javascript:%3B',
            'http:\/\/www.feathersflights.com\/',
            'http:\/\/www.feathersflights.com\/search\/label\/sewing101',
            'http:\/\/www.feathersflights.com\/search\/label\/You%20Flew%3A%20Sewing%20Linkup',
            'http:\/\/www.feathersflights.com\/p\/tutorials-and-past-projects.html',
            'https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/feathersflights',
            'https:\/\/twitter.com\/feathersflights',
            'http:\/\/pinterest.com\/feathersflights\/',
            'http:\/\/instagram.com\/feathersflights#',
            'https:\/\/plus.google.com\/u\/0\/101032706297651559107',
            'http:\/\/www.bloglovin.com\/blog\/2866677\/feathers-flights-a-creative-sewing',
            'mailto:feathersflights%40gmail.com',
            'http:\/\/feeds.feedburner.com\/FeathersFlights',
            'http:\/\/www.blogger.com\/rearrange?blogID%3D7070182830087816119%26widgetType%3DHTML%26widgetId%3DHTML6%26action%3DeditWidget%26sectionId%3Dheader-right',
            'http:\/\/www.feathersflights.com\/p\/about.html',
            'http:\/\/www.feathersflights.com\/p\/cant-live-without.html',
            'http:\/\/www.feathersflights.com\/p\/sponsor.html',
            'http:\/\/feathersflights.bigcartel.com\/',
            'http:\/\/www.blogger.com\/rearrange?blogID%3D7070182830087816119%26widgetType%3DHTML%26widgetId%3DHTML7%26action%3DeditWidget%26sectionId%3Dcrosscol',
            'http:\/\/www.blogger.com\/rearrange?blogID%3D7070182830087816119%26widgetType%3DHTML%26widgetId%3DHTML4%26action%3DeditWidget%26sectionId%3Dsidebar-right-1',
            'http:\/\/www.blogger.com\/rearrange?blogID%3D7070182830087816119%26widgetType%3DHTML%26widgetId%3DHTML15%26action%3DeditWidget%26sectionId%3Dsidebar-right-1',
            'http:\/\/www.blogger.com\/rearrange?blogID%3D7070182830087816119%26widgetType%3DText%26widgetId%3DText2%26action%3DeditWidget%26sectionId%3Dsidebar-right-1',
            'http:\/\/www.blogger.com\/rearrange?blogID%3D7070182830087816119%26widgetType%3DCustomSearch%26widgetId%3DCustomSearch1%26action%3DeditWidget%26sectionId%3Dsidebar-right-1',
            'http:\/\/www.blogger.com\/rearrange?blogID%3D7070182830087816119%26widgetType%3DText%26widgetId%3DText3%26action%3DeditWidget%26sectionId%3Dsidebar-right-1',
            'http:\/\/www.blogger.com\/rearrange?blogID%3D7070182830087816119%26widgetType%3DFollowers%26widgetId%3DFollowers1%26action%3DeditWidget%26sectionId%3Dsidebar-right-1'
        ]
    },
    yAxis:{
        min:0,
        title:{text:"Number of Links"},
        labels:{style:{width:'1000px'}
    }
},
tooltip:{
    formatter:function() {
        return '' + this.series.name +': '+ this.y;
    }
},
plotOptions:{
    bar:{
        dataLabels:{
            enabled:1
        }
    }
},
credits:{enabled:false},
series:[
    {
        name:'Number of Links',
        data:[86,61,35,34,32,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30],
        color:'#F79646'
    }
]
});
```

});

## Link to the Chart on JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vCrc7/1/

Any suggestions?

Comment: Changing the label alignment to 'left' [as in this example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/labels-x/) might be a better starting point.

Comment: MischaNix - Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately this (see http://jsfiddle.net/vCrc7/2/) is not the effect I'm looking for. I'd still like to keep the categories to the left of the axis, only wrapped and with a fixed width...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could forcefully break up the long string.  For instance this inserts a `<br/>` every 25 chars:

```
        labels:{
            formatter: function(){
                var rV = '';
                var someCat = this.value;
                while (someCat .length > 0) {
                  rV += someCat.substring(0, 25) + '<br/>';
                  someCat = someCat.substring(25);
                }
                return rV ;                    
            }
        },
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vCrc7/4/).

Comment: This is a great solution! Do you know if there is a way to turn off the auto-wrap as well? Currently, it continues to do an additional wrap wherever it finds a hyphen or space...

Comment: I would recommend outputting the labels in html with the `useHTML: true` flag, and then using CSS to style it. http://jsfiddle.net/vCrc7/7/